# Jquery append html file in a div repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a scroll to add `.html` file in a div. But i have one problem here. When i scroll down my jquery code appending many time page.html file also when i scroll up it appending `page.html` many time. What is the problem in my code anyone can help me here ?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="abc"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 300) {

      $.get("page.html", function(data) {
         $(".abc").append(data);
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: it's appending every time the scroll event happens. You do realize it happens quite often while... scrolling... right?

Comment: @KevinB what is the correct way dear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append the html file only once with the help of a simple variable

```
var added = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 300 && added == false) {
        added = true;
        $.get("page.html", function(data) {
            $(".abc").append(data);
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: all is same. It is repeating

Comment: @KevinB : i have updated the answer, i missed to type the full if condition $(window).scrollTop() >= 300 && added == false

Comment: @Deep i have tested your updated answer it is not fixed my problem. It is not stopped repeating when i scroll down and scroll up.

Comment: i guess your ajax is taking some time and before that you have scrolled few times, i have updated it again to avoid any further ajax call, hope this should help you.

Comment: thank you for insterested my problem. Yes i tested your second updated answer now and problem is continue. Almost same problem here. I don't understand why it is not stoped to append.

Comment: i think you got it working now. i created plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/QiKYPbyFQzAtVq76qnsM just to show that only :)

Comment: but i don't understand what is the problem in my question why some one gives me -vote :S

Comment: yeah down voting should be with at least an explanation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117013/discussion-between-devstud-and-deep).

Comment: can i ask you one question ?